# How to get specific fields or update theme and get the relation fildes from api calls in yii2 REST API?

Tags: rest, yii2

I'm trying default yii2 api rest calls `GET` to get some model fields or `PUT` to update some model fields but I can't find a way to do this. I can only get all the fields or update theme all. Any help to do this? And how can I get the related relational field to this model?

I'm trying like this like

```
GET localhost/my-website-name/api/web/v1/vendors/
PUT localhost/my-website-name/api/web/v1/vendors/1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello i manage to find a solution for this situations

1. first get some model fields only and with related entities fildes:

   ```
   public function fields() {
   return [
       'name',
       'phone_number',
       'minimum_order_amount',
       'time_order_open',
       'time_order_close',
       'delivery_fee',
       'halal',
       'featured',
       'disable_ordering',
       'delivery_duration',
       'working_hours',
       'longitude',
       'latitude',
       'image',
       'owner' => function() {
           $owner = Owners::findOne($this->owner_id);
           return array($owner);
       }
    ];
   }
   ```
2. if you want to remove some fildes

   ```
   public function fields()
   {
     $fields=parent::fields();
     unset($fields['id']);
     return $fields;
   }
   ```
3. update only specific fields

   ```
   public function beforeSave($insert)
    {
     $lockedValues = ['name', 'halal', 'featured', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'image', 'status', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
       foreach ($lockedValues as $lockedValue) {
         if ($this->attributes[$lockedValue] != $this->oldAttributes[$lockedValue])
           throw new ForbiddenHttpException($lockedValue . " can't be changed.");
     }

   return parent::beforeSave($insert); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

one way that I know for customizing fields is overriding fields function in your model like this

```
   public function fields() {
   return [
       'id',
        'iso3' => function() {
           return base64_encode($this->iso3);
       }
   ];
}
```

Comment: @yafter thanks for your answer, but this only returning specific value how can we update specific value only too

Comment: unfortunately I don't have any experience about that.This is a question for me too.

Answer (score 1):

> How to get specific fields and get the relation fields from api calls?

By default, [yii\db\ActiveRecord::fields()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-arrayabletrait.html#fields()-detail) returns all model attributes which have been populated from DB as fields, while [yii\db\ActiveRecord::extraFields()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-arrayabletrait.html#extraFields()-detail) should return the names of model's relations.

Take this model for example:

```
class Image extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'owner_id' => 'Owner ID',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'url' => 'Url',
            'created_at' => 'Created At',
            'updated_at' => 'Updated At',
        ];
    }

    public function getOwner()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Owner::className(), ['id' => 'owner_id']);
    }

    public function extraFields()
    {
        return ['owner'];
    }
}
```

Here I did override the *extraFields()* method to define the **owner** relationship. Now if I want to retreive all **images** but selecting **id** and **name** fields only and each resource should also hold its related owner data I would simply request this url:

```
GET example.com/images?fields=id,name&expand=owner
```

- *note: you can also use comma separation to expand more than one relation*

In case you want to permanently remove some fields like **created_at** and **updated_at** you can also override the `fields()` method:

```
public function fields()
{
    $fields = parent::fields();
    unset($fields['created_at'], $fields['updated_at'], $fields['owner_id']);
    return $fields;
    /*
        // or could also be:
        return ['id', 'name','url'];
    */
}
```

this way the following request should only return **image**'s *id*, *name* and *url* fields along with their related **owner** :

```
GET example.com/images?expand=owner
```

If **owner**'s fields should be filtered too then override its `fields()` method too in its related class or a child class of it that you tie to the **image** model by using it when defining the relation.

See [official documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-resources.html) for further details.

> PUT to update some model fields

Yii only updates dirty attributes. so when doing:

```
PUT example.com/images/1 {"name": "abc"}
```

the generated SQL query should only update the **name** column of `id=1` inside database.